# how will I know the value of parseobject

Tags: android, parse-platform

com as backend to my android application but when I try to display the objects returned from the server it does  not display the values exactly instead displays as com.parse.ParseObject@c1.... so Can someone please help me with this?
    My code is

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Constants.wifiClass);
                query.whereEqualTo("keyvalue", -72);
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            try {
                                Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.get(0).fetch().getInt("keyvalue") + " scores");
                            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Object[] objectArray = scoreList.toArray();

                                location=String.valueOf(objectArray[0]);
                        } else {
                            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                            location=e.toString();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Please be more specific and narrow your problem down a bit more. What exactly do you want to have displayed? Is there an error log we can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the callback, `ParseObject` will represent a row. You can access each field using `scoreList.get(0).get("<field>")`. More details [here](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html).